# Oracle - How can create a procedure with 'and' that doesn't require parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to create a procedure that will scan through all items in a table, and when three conditions are met, it will update a certain value. Here's what I have when I specify what to update:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NoNullRatingsForFuture(IN_GAME NUMBER) AS
BEGIN

  UPDATE GAMES
     SET rating_id = 10
   WHERE game_id = IN_GAME;

END NoNullRatingsForFuture;
```

Example usage:

```
EXECUTE NoNullRatingsForFuture(7);
```

However, I want to make the procedure scan the entire table, and update it, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NoNullRatingsForFuture AS
BEGIN

   UPDATE GAMES
      SET rating_id = 10
    WHERE game_id = game_id 
      AND rating_id = NULL 
      AND release_date > SYSDATE;

END NoNullRatingsForFuture;
```

Example usage:

```
EXECUTE NoNullRatingsForFuture;
```

Essentially, if the `rating` is null and the date is above the current date, change the `rating_id` to 10. Also, release_date is stored in `dd-month-yy` format, if that helps.

That procedure compiles fine, and I can execute fine, but `rating_id` is still null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason you are storing the release date as a string, not as a `DATE`?  Your question shows just one of a number of subtle issues that can occur when dates aren't stored as dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NoNullRatingsForFuture AS
BEGIN

  UPDATE GAMES
     SET rating_id = 10
   WHERE rating_id IS NULL 
     AND TO_DATE(release_date, 'DD-MONTH-YY') > SYSDATE;

END NoNullRatingsForFuture;
```

Couple of points:

1. NULL isn't a value - it's a placeholder for the ***lack of*** one.  You need to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` to find such instances to deal with them appropriately
2. The `release_date` should be stored as a DATE in order to compare to SYSDATE.  The Oracle DATE data type includes time.  Otherwise you need to use [TO_DATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) on such columns (which won't support an index if one exists on `release_date`) to convert the value into a DATE.
3. Scanning the table is not efficient - it's possible `WHERE game_id = game_id` will be optimized out of the equation, but I don't recommend the practice.  Likewise for `WHERE 1 = 1`, unless using it in dynamic SQL to make additional conditions easier to concatenate.

Comment: Re point 3 - Oracle will always optimize out "no-op" comparisons like `1=1`, and `game_id=game_id` is equivalent to `game_id IS NOT NULL` and will be optimized as such.